# Can you override DOM events on a component?

Tags: angular, events

I'm working on writing a custom input component and wanted to implement a `(change)` event for it. I set everything up with an `@Output` but when I tested it out I noticed the listener function was getting called twice, once with the value I expected and once with an `Event` object. Confused, I dug deeper and found that putting a `(change)` event listener on my custom component registered the DOM event even though I had an `@Output('change')`. This caused ANY `change` event on any of my components children (`<input>` tags) to call my listener.

You can see the behavior here on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-forwarding-change-event)

Is there a way to say "Hey Angular, just register my `@Output` and that's it"? Or are we just forbidden to use any event names that are the same as DOM ones?